# Huge Update or Inserts into DB2 using JAVA and JPA 1.0

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jakarta-ee, db2

I have a JAVA requirement where i have 1500 records that I have to update or insert into the database.

If a record exists with userId, then update it.
If a record does not exist with userId, then Insert it.

And, if there is an error in lets say, 10th record,,,I need to get 
the error code for that record.

It looks like I have 2 options using JPA 1.0

A) Fire a select to check if record exists. If yes, then fire update. If not, fire insert.

B) Fire an insert always,,,but i get an uniqe record exception, only then fire an update query..

Are there any other more efficient ways ? how can this be done with as few queries and as quick as possible ?

ENV- JAVA, JPA 1.0, DB2

Comment: No idea about the environment, but what is described sounds like a use case for the `MERGE` statement; I'd have included a doc reference, but no mention of nor a tag included, to denote the DB2 variant, nor mention of what release of whatever DB2 was given.

Comment: Is it really "only" 1500 records? or could it be 15000 or 150000 records?

Answer (score 0):

You did not specify which version of DB2 you use and on which system. Anyway, check if MERGE statement is available on your DB:

LUW from 9.5.0: http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0010873.html

Z/OS from 10.0.0: http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_10.0.0/sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_sql_merge.html

Another way is to do delete + insert on every record (poor performance).

Third option is to create dynamic one delete statement with listed ID/KEY in where clause from data you are going to update, fire delete and then insert all data.

Performance of every option will depend on table specification, indexes etc.

Answer (score -2):

you can write query in mysql as below

//suppose a as pk
INSERT INTO table (a,b,c) VALUES (1,2,3)
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE c=c+1,b=b+1;
here update will run when record with pk as a=1 is already present

refer below link http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Comment: The OP is (a) using DB2, not MySQL and (b) looking for a JPA solution rather than a solution expressed in SQL